# Method: licenseAssignments.listForProduct get Error

Tags: api, google-api

y try to get the [licenses](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/reference/rest/v1/licenseAssignments/listForProduct?apix_params=%7B%22productId%22%3A%22Google-Apps%22%2C%22customerId%22%3A%22932038514972%22%7D) in the organization but  in the page get the next error,

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "Backend Error",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Backend Error",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't know if the service has a problem or if I put wrong parameters.

[image]

Method: licenseAssignments.listForProduct, i need the licenses per users

Comment: it only shows per product you need the product id.  This method has nothing to do with the user.  You need to be workspace admin to run it though.

Comment: solved, thanks, and this API show de user and the license and the problem in my case is the customer Id i put a wrong value.